# 2nd monitor won't turn on after computer power off

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, power-supply

I've got two identical screens both connected via DisplayPort to a GTX 970. Then one day only one of my monitors turned on after I turned on the PC.
My main monitor turns on just fine - every time.

Haven't experienced an issue when the monitors turn off due to standby while the computer is on. Only when booting from cold.

In order for me to turn on my 2nd monitor I have to unplug the power cord and plug it back in. This usually turns it on. Pressing the power button on the monitor does nothing.

I've tried changing the monitor, my new replaced monitor does the exact same thing. So it isn't a monitor issue.

I've tried switching the port (still DP) they're connected via on the gfx card. No change. So it isn't a gfx card issue.

I've tried switching around the power adapter each monitor uses. So it isn't an adapter issue.

I don't even. Where do I go from here?

Comment: Have you checked whether Windows recognises that the monitor is present? Try going into the screen resolution settings and click on "Detect". Also check that Windows isn't showing the 2nd monitor grey'd out. I see that sometimes even though the monitor is present, I have to manually enable it.

Comment: Windows doesn't recognise the monitor is present until I unplug the power (of the monitor) and plug it back in. I can't even turn on the monitor on the power button, which I think you usually can. But is met with the "No signal" message on screen.

Comment: That means you CAN turn it on, it just isn't receiving a signal. You did the checks I suggested?

Comment: Yes did check that. When the monitor is off, it's completely turned off, like without power. Windows doesn't detect it.

Comment: Perhaps I should take some pictures that might explain things a bit better

Comment: Good. maybe also a screenshot of the screen resolution window

Comment: Turns out it actually was the adapter. I must have been confused by the cable mess the first time I tested it :/